# JMeter error when generating dashboard at end of test

Tags: jmeter

For the last few weeks I have been using JMeters automatic dashboard generation at end of test w/ command:

```
./jmeter -n -t <test JMX file> -l <test log file> -e -o <Path to output folder>
```

However about 50% of the time the terminal freezes exactly 1 second before the test is scheduled to end without generating the dashboard. So I want to manually build the dash report from my log.jtl file using:
 `./jmeter -g <log file> -o <Path to output folder>`

But when I run this command in terminal I get the error: 
 `An error occurred: Error while processing samples:Mismatch between expected number of columns:16 and columns in CSV file:15, check your jmeter.save.saveservice.* configuration`

The only thing I have in user.properties is (taken directly from http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html):

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.label = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.time = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time = true 
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format = ms
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format = yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
```

Running `./jmeter -g <log file> -o <Path to output folder>` with and without these additions to user.properties still causes the same error listed.

Please help!

UPDATE: When I run a test from nongui mode and it completes ('tidying up...' is printed to the terminal) as opposed to freezing, my dashboard generation `./jmeter -g <log file> -o <Path to output folder>` works correctly. So it seems the freezing problem lies in the test construction. The test ends by hitting a certain time of day, say 4:00 pm, which is added to the jmeter test in the thread group scheduler. Does anyone have any suggestions to how I can fix this? Has anyone experienced a similar problem?

Comment: Can you please check the properties in `jmeter.properties` file?

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam check jmeter.properties for what?

Comment: Check for `jmeter.save.saveservice.*` properties in jmeter.properties whether you have configured it correctly or not.

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam it is currently configured to the defaults, which includes the above lines from user.properties

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam is there something I should add?

Comment: I hope all the graphs configured in JMeter properties file. Can you double check please?http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_after_load_test

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam Nevermind! They were commented out in my jmeter.properties file. My mistake, I am now getting another error but I will continue to debug and post if I cannot solve myself. Thanks Naveen!!

Comment: You need to un-comment those properties in JMeter.properties. Please let me know how it goes :) Thanks.

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam it says at the top of jmeter.properties that the document should not be modified , and to only modify user.properties. Should I ignore this and leave those lines uncommented?

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam either way with the lines present or not present in jmeter.properties, the same error accurs. Do you have any other suggestions? Also in what file are those graph classes located? I believe they will all be present since half the time when I generate the report at the end of the test they generate successfully

Comment: Actually you have to copy the properties from JMeter and use it user.properties. I sometimes use JMeter.properties direclty. I am not able to reproduce your issue. :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know it's a little bit late but i'm still answering this in case other people had the same problem, as i did.

In my case, after making sure the jmeter.properties and the user.properties were identical, i opened the log file. You know, the .jtl one, and deleted the last line that was cutted out.
Then, just execute the command line `jmeter -g <log file> -o <Path to output folder>` and worked just fine.

It happens when the execution doesn't end properly.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message you are most probably not using the same jmeter.properties + user.properties between the lod test and the generation.

Ensure you do.

Second, regarding the first issue, check that you donnt have some disk space issue or you didn't face an OutOfMemoryError and if issue persists please report a bug.

Comment: Would the properties for load generation be in reportgenerator.properties? In that file I don't see any properties with the title `save.saveservice` which are the only properties I've added to user.properties and jmeter.properties.

Comment: Check out my update. It looks like dashboard generation is working but not when the test freezes at the last second. I'm thinking it has something to do with how I end the test from the scheduler at an exact time of day. You're suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure every single data line in your csv, delimited by coma, match the columns number. I got the same exception because of that, for example...

> timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,Connect
>   1569471061857,3918,200,OK,Stress,text
>   1569471061857,3918,200,OK,Stress,text
>   1569471061857,3918,200,OK,Stress,text
>   1569471061857,3918,200,OK,St

In this case, the header and most data have 6 columns, but the last line isn't complete (because I prematurely interrupted the execution) the last line ended with 5 columns instead of 6 and that caused the exception.

Good luck.